# Python: Space Invaders Score System

Tags: python, pygame

Been trying to add a scoring system to my game but I keep getting a weird error and now I'm stumped. Here's the code:

```
##Space Invaders##

import pygame
import sys
from random import shuffle
from pygame.locals import *

##CONSTANTS##

## Colors ##
GRAY = (100,100,100)
NAVYBLUE = (60,60,100)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)
ORANGE = (255,128,0)
PURPLE = (255,0,255)
CYAN = (0,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
NEARBLACK = (19,15,48)
COMBLUE = (233,232,255)
## Player ##
PLAYERWIDTH = 40
PLAYERHEIGHT = 10
PLAYERCOLOR = COMBLUE
PLAYER1 = 'Player 1'
PLAYERSPEED = 5
PLAYERCOLOR = GREEN
## Display ##
GAMETITLE =('SPACE INVADERS')
DISPLAYWIDTH = 640
DISPLAYHEIGHT = 480
BGCOLOR = NEARBLACK
XMARGIN = 50
YMARGIN = 50
## Bullet ##
BULLETWIDTH = 5
BULLETHEIGHT = 5
BULLETOFFSET = 700
## Enemy ##
ENEMYWIDTH = 25
ENEMYHEIGHT = 25
ENEMYNAME = 'Enemy'
ENEMYGAP = 20
ARRAYWIDTH = 10
ARRAYHEIGHT = 4
MOVETIME = 1000
MOVEX = 10
MOVEY = ENEMYHEIGHT
TIMEOFFSET = 300
## SCORE ##
score=0
## This allows for shooting bullets while moving without
## the inputs interupting each other.
DIRECT_DICT = {pygame.K_LEFT  : (-1),
               pygame.K_RIGHT : (1)}

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width = PLAYERWIDTH
        self.height = PLAYERHEIGHT
        self.image = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.color = PLAYERCOLOR
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.name = PLAYER1
        self.speed = PLAYERSPEED
        self.vectorx = 0

    def update(self, keys, *args):
        for key in DIRECT_DICT:
            if keys[key]:
                self.rect.x += DIRECT_DICT[key] * self.speed

        self.checkForSide()
        self.image.fill(self.color)

    def checkForSide(self):
        if self.rect.right > DISPLAYWIDTH:
            self.rect.right = DISPLAYWIDTH
            self.vectorx = 0
        elif self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
            self.vectorx = 0

class Blocker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, side, color, row, column):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width = side
        self.height = side
        self.color = color
        self.image = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.name = 'blocker'
        self.row = row
        self.column = column

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect, color, vectory, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width = BULLETWIDTH
        self.height = BULLETHEIGHT
        self.color = color
        self.image = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = rect.bottom
        self.name = 'bullet'
        self.vectory = vectory
        self.speed = speed

    def update(self, *args):
        self.oldLocation = (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
        self.rect.y += self.vectory * self.speed

        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()

        elif self.rect.bottom > 500:
            self.kill()

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, row, column):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width = ENEMYWIDTH
        self.height = ENEMYHEIGHT
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.image = self.setImage()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.name = 'enemy'
        self.vectorx = 1
        self.moveNumber = 0
        self.moveTime = MOVETIME
        self.timeOffset = row * TIMEOFFSET
        self.timer = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.timeOffset

    def update(self, keys, currentTime):
        if currentTime - self.timer > self.moveTime:
            if self.moveNumber < 6:
                self.rect.x += MOVEX * self.vectorx
                self.moveNumber += 1
            elif self.moveNumber >= 6:
                self.vectorx *= -1
                self.moveNumber = 0
                self.rect.y += MOVEY
                if self.moveTime > 100:
                    self.moveTime -= 50
            self.timer = currentTime

    def setImage(self):
        if self.row == 0:
            image = pygame.image.load('alien1.png')
        elif self.row == 1:
            image = pygame.image.load('alien2.png')
        elif self.row == 2:
            image = pygame.image.load('alien3.png')
        else:
            image = pygame.image.load('alien1.png')
        image.convert_alpha()
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (self.width, self.height))

        return image

class Text(object):
    def __init__(self, font, size, message, color, rect, surface):
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(font, size)
        self.message = message
        self.surface = self.font.render(self.message, True, color)
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.setRect(rect)
    def setRect(self,rect):
        self.rect.centerx = rect.centerx - 5
        self.rect.centery = rect.centery - 5
    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.surface, self.rect)

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.displaySurf, self.displayRect = self.makeScreen()
        self.gameStart = True
        self.gameOver = False
        self.gameWon = False
        self.beginGame = False
        self.laserSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('laser.ogg')
        self.startLaser = pygame.mixer.Sound('alienLaser.ogg')
        self.playIntroSound = True
    def resetGame(self):
        self.gameStart = True
        self.needToMakeEnemies = True
        self.introMessage1 = Text('orena.ttf', 50,'Space Invaders',GREEN, self.displayRect,self.displaySurf)
        self.introMessage2 = Text('orena.ttf', 25,'Press Space to Continue',GREEN, self.displayRect,self.displaySurf)
        self.introMessage2.rect.top = self.introMessage1.rect.bottom + 5
        self.gameOverMessage = Text('orena.ttf', 50,'GAME OVER',GREEN, self.displayRect,self.displaySurf)
        self.gameWinMessage = Text('orena.ttf',50,'Congrats You Won',GREEN,self.displayRect,self.displaySurf)
        self.gameWinMessage2 = Text('orena.ttf', 30,'Click Space to return to the menu',GREEN, self.displayRect,self.displaySurf)
        self.gameWinMessage2.rect.top = self.gameWinMessage.rect.bottom + 5
        self.scoreText = Text('orena.ttf',10,'Score:',WHITE,self.displayRect,self.displaySurf)
        self.player = self.makePlayer()
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.greenBullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.blockerGroup1 = self.makeBlockers(0)
        self.blockerGroup2 = self.makeBlockers(1)
        self.blockerGroup3 = self.makeBlockers(2)
        self.blockerGroup4 = self.makeBlockers(3)
        self.allBlockers = pygame.sprite.Group(self.blockerGroup1, self.blockerGroup2,self.blockerGroup3, self.blockerGroup4)
        self.allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(self.player, self.allBlockers)
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.fps = 60
        self.score  = score
        self.enemyMoves = 0
        self.enemyBulletTimer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.gameOver = False
        self.gameWon = False
        self.gameOverTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.gameWinTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if self.playIntroSound:
            self.startLaser.play()
            self.playIntroSound = False

    def makeBlockers(self, number=1):
        blockerGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for row in range(5):
            for column in range(7):
                blocker = Blocker(10, GREEN, row, column)
                blocker.rect.x = 50 + (150 * number) + (column * blocker.width)
                blocker.rect.y = 375 + (row * blocker.height)
                blockerGroup.add(blocker)

        for blocker in blockerGroup:
            if (blocker.column == 0 and blocker.row == 0
                or blocker.column == 6 and blocker.row == 0):
                blocker.kill()

        return blockerGroup

    def checkForEnemyBullets(self):
        redBulletsGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

        for bullet in self.bullets:
            if bullet.color == RED:
                redBulletsGroup.add(bullet)

        for bullet in redBulletsGroup:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet, self.player):
                if self.player.color == GREEN:
                    self.player.color = YELLOW
                elif self.player.color == YELLOW:
                    self.player.color = RED
                elif self.player.color == RED:
                    self.gameOver = True
                    self.gameOverTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                bullet.kill()

    def shootEnemyBullet(self, rect):
        if (pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.enemyBulletTimer) > BULLETOFFSET:
            self.bullets.add(Bullet(rect, RED, 1, 5))
            self.allSprites.add(self.bullets)
            self.enemyBulletTimer = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def findEnemyShooter(self):
        columnList = []
        for enemy in self.enemies:
            columnList.append(enemy.column)

        #get rid of duplicate columns
        columnSet = set(columnList)
        columnList = list(columnSet)
        shuffle(columnList)
        column = columnList[0]
        enemyList = []
        rowList = []

        for enemy in self.enemies:
            if enemy.column == column:
                rowList.append(enemy.row)

        row = max(rowList)

        for enemy in self.enemies:
            if enemy.column == column and enemy.row == row:
                self.shooter = enemy

    def makeScreen(self):
        pygame.display.set_caption(GAMETITLE)
        displaySurf = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAYWIDTH, DISPLAYHEIGHT))
        displayRect = displaySurf.get_rect()
        displaySurf.fill(BGCOLOR)
        displaySurf.convert()

        return displaySurf, displayRect

    def makePlayer(self):
        player = Player()
        #Place the player centerx and five pixels from the bottom
        player.rect.centerx = self.displayRect.centerx
        player.rect.bottom = self.displayRect.bottom - 5

        return player

    def makeEnemies(self):
        enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()

        for row in range(ARRAYHEIGHT):
            for column in range(ARRAYWIDTH):
                enemy = Enemy(row, column)
                enemy.rect.x = XMARGIN + (column * (ENEMYWIDTH + ENEMYGAP))
                enemy.rect.y = YMARGIN + (row * (ENEMYHEIGHT + ENEMYGAP))
                enemies.add(enemy)

        return enemies

    def checkInput(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.terminate()

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_SPACE and len(self.greenBullets) < 1:
                    if self.score < 1000:    
                        bullet = Bullet(self.player.rect, GREEN, -1, 20)
                        self.greenBullets.add(bullet)
                        self.bullets.add(self.greenBullets)
                        self.allSprites.add(self.bullets)
                        self.laserSound.play()

                elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    self.terminate()

    def calculate_score(self, row):
        scores = {0: 30,
                1: 20,
                2: 20,
                3: 10,
                4: 10,
                5: choice([50, 100, 150, 300])
                }

        score = scores[row]
        self.score += score
        return score

    def gameStartInput(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                self.gameWon = False
                self.gameOver = False
                self.gameStart = False
                self.beginGame = True
    def gameOverInput(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                self.gameStart = True
                self.beginGame = False
                self.gameOver = False
                self.gameWon = False
    def gameWonInput(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                self.gameStart = True
                self.beginGame = False
                self.gameOver = False
                self.gameWon = False
    def checkCollisions(self):
        self.checkForEnemyBullets()
        enemiesdict = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.enemies, True, True)
        if enemiesdict:
            for value in enemiesdict.values():
                for currentSprite in value:
                    self.killedRow = currentSprite.row
                    self.killedColumn = currentSprite.column
                    score = self.calculate_score(currentSprite.row)
                    self.enemies.remove(currentSprite)
                    self.allSprites.remove(currentSprite)
        pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.enemies, self.allBlockers, False, True)
        self.collide_green_blockers()
        self.collide_red_blockers()

    def collide_green_blockers(self):
        for bullet in self.greenBullets:
            casting = Bullet(self.player.rect, GREEN, -1, 20)
            casting.rect = bullet.rect.copy()
            for pixel in range(bullet.speed):
                hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(casting,self.allBlockers)
                if hit:
                    hit.kill()
                    bullet.kill()
                    break
                casting.rect.y -= 1

    def collide_red_blockers(self):
        reds = (shot for shot in self.bullets if shot.color == RED)
        red_bullets = pygame.sprite.Group(reds)
        pygame.sprite.groupcollide(red_bullets, self.allBlockers, True, True)

    def checkGameOver(self):
        if len(self.enemies) == 0:
            self.gameWon = True
            self.gameStart = False
            self.beginGame = False
            self.gameOverTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            self.gameWinTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        else:
            for enemy in self.enemies:
                if enemy.rect.bottom > DISPLAYHEIGHT:
                    self.gameOver = True
                    self.gameStart = False
                    self.beginGame = False
                    self.gameOverTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def terminate(self):
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def mainLoop(self):
        while True:
            if self.gameStart:
                self.resetGame()
                self.gameOver = False
                self.displaySurf.fill(BGCOLOR)
                self.introMessage1.draw(self.displaySurf)
                self.introMessage2.draw(self.displaySurf)
                self.scoreText2 = Text('orena.ttf', 20, str(self.score), GREEN, 85, 5)
                self.scoreText.draw(self.screen)
                self.scoreText2.draw(self.screen)
                self.gameStartInput()
                pygame.display.update()
            elif self.gameOver:
                self.playIntroSound = True
                self.displaySurf.fill(BGCOLOR)
                self.gameOverMessage.draw(self.displaySurf)
                #prevent users from exiting the GAME OVER screen
                #too quickly
                if (pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.gameOverTime) > 2000:
                    self.gameOverInput()
                pygame.display.update()
            elif self.gameWon:
                self.gameOver = False
                self.playIntroSound = True
                self.displaySurf.fill(BGCOLOR)
                self.gameWinMessage.draw(self.displaySurf)
                self.gameWinMessage2.draw(self.displaySurf)
                if (pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.gameWinTime) > 2000:
                    self.gameWonInput()
                pygame.display.update()

            elif self.beginGame:
                if self.needToMakeEnemies:
                    self.enemies = self.makeEnemies()
                    self.allSprites.add(self.enemies)
                    self.needToMakeEnemies = False
                    pygame.event.clear()

                else:
                    currentTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    self.displaySurf.fill(BGCOLOR)
                    self.checkInput()
                    self.allSprites.update(self.keys, currentTime)
                    self.scoreText2 = Text('orena.ttf', 20, str(self.score), WHITE, 85, 5)
                    self.scoreText.draw(self.screen)
                    self.scoreText2.draw(self.screen)
                    if len(self.enemies) > 0:
                        self.findEnemyShooter()
                        self.shootEnemyBullet(self.shooter.rect)
                    self.checkCollisions()
                    self.allSprites.draw(self.displaySurf)
                    self.blockerGroup1.draw(self.displaySurf)
                    pygame.display.update()
                    self.checkGameOver()
                    self.clock.tick(self.fps)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainLoop()
```

Error (Line 178):

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'centerx'
```

Game files like pictures, sound files, etc. can be changed/replaced. If you need the files let me know. However I'd prefer if I could keep those private. 
Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What line does that error refer to?

Comment: Oops sorry. Line 178

Comment: BTW, the downvotes you are getting are probably because you didn't create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but pasted everything in, instead.

Comment: I'll make sure to do that next time. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this class:

```
class Text(object):
    def __init__(self, font, size, message, color, rect, surface):
```

In the init you have:

```
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.setRect(rect)
```

Notice you are setting `self.rect` but sending `rect` to the function

It should be

```
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.setRect(self.rect)
```

**The issue also comes from this call:**

```
self.scoreText2 = Text('orena.ttf', 20, str(self.score), GREEN, 85, 5)
```

Most places you call it by sending something like:

```
self.introMessage1 = Text('orena.ttf', 50,'Space Invaders',GREEN, self.displayRect,self.displaySurf)
```

`self.displayRect` has a centerx. The `int` 85 does not.

**Debugging**

Read and understand your error message:

It is telling you `rect` is an `int` but you are expecting a `rect` type. Print your values until you find where it changes from being correct to wrong to narrow down the issue.

Also, by creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, a lot of the noise goes away and you are able to focus on your issue and can often catch errors like these yourself.